# Nextjs is not rendering CSS in Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, server-side-rendering, emotion

When I update react 17 to react 18 in the nextjs project. Nextjs is not rendering CSS in Server-Side Rendering. How can I solve this problem anyone faced this problem before after updating react 17 to react 18??

_app.tsx:

```js
import { AppProvider } from "contexts/AppContext";
import SettingsProvider from "contexts/SettingContext";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import Router from "next/router";
import { Fragment, ReactElement, ReactNode, useEffect } from "react";
import MuiTheme from "theme/MuiTheme";

type MyAppProps = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPage & {
    getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
  };
};

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: MyAppProps) => {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement!.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SettingsProvider>
        <AppProvider>
          <MuiTheme>
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
          </MuiTheme>
        </AppProvider>
      </SettingsProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

// Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
// every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
// perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
// be server-side rendered.
//
// App.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
//   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
//   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

//   return { ...appProps };
// };

export default App;
```

=============================================================================

_document.tsx

```js
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createEmotionServer from "@emotion/server/create-instance";
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import React from "react";
import createEmotionCache from "../src/createEmotionCache";

export default class Bazar extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
Bazar.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  const cache = createEmotionCache();
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
        (
          <CacheProvider value={cache}>
            <App {...props} />
          </CacheProvider>
        ),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  // This is important. It prevents emotion to render invalid HTML.
  // See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26561#issuecomment-855286153
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html);
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(" ")}`}
      key={style.key}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ));

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), ...emotionStyleTags],
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

react18 In nextjs@12.1.6, the emotionCache is currently not available. so remove getInitialProps, which is what I've done so far.

Related documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#customizing-renderpage

To prepare for React 18, we recommend avoiding customizing getInitialProps and renderPage, if possible.